# Assigning different classes to a particular object depending on user input in C++

Tags: c++, class

I have considered an object 'genObj'. This object can be of the class phones,   laptops, shoes, or books.
I wish to take user input varying from 1-4, and accordingly assign genObj to a praticular class.

I wish to do this because I have to add these objects to data files. I am maintaining 4 separate data files for the different classes, and a value to fileName is also assigned accordingly.

```
 switch(mode)
    {
     case 1:
        phones genObj;
        strcpy(fileName,"phonesDatabase.dat");
        break;
     case 2:
        computers genObj;
        strcpy(fileName,"computersDatabase.dat");
        break;
     case 3:
        shoes genObj;
        strcpy(fileName,"shoesDatabase.dat)";
        break;
     case 4:
        books genObj;
        strcpy(fileName,"booksDatabase.dat");
        break;
    }
```

Doing this, hovewer, gives the following error:

```
"Multiple declaration for genObj in function add(int)"
```

The values are assigned to fileName without problem as I have declared

```
char fileName[20];
```

globally, and it gets initialized later. However, since the object genObj can be of different classes, it cannot be initialized like this.

If I am not able to assign genObj different classes according to user input, I will have to separate the code into 4 parts, each for one class. and that would be too cumbersome, and inelegant.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are writing in C++ (based on your tags)  use C++!  Remove  `strcpy` from your vocabulary.

Comment: And the design pattern you are looking for is called a Factory.   Google it, please.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot decide the type of an object dynamically at run-time.

Seems like you should use *polymorphism* in this situation:

First define an abstract class, say `object`, that defines the behavior that you use to access your `genObj`. That is, everything `phones`, `computers`, `shoes`, and `books` have in commons.

Then make those four sub-classes of `object` and then something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<object> genObj;

switch(mode)
{
    case 1:
        genObj = std::make_unique<phones>();
        strcpy(fileName, "phonesDatabase.dat");
        break;
    case 2:
        genObj = std::make_unique<computers>();
        strcpy(fileName, "computersDatabase.dat");
        break;
    case 3:
        genObj = std::make_unique<shoes>();
        strcpy(fileName, "shoesDatabase.dat)";
        break;
    case 4:
        genObj = std::make_unique<books>();
        strcpy(fileName, "booksDatabase.dat");
        break;
}
```

(Note that `make_unique` is a feature only in the most recent C++ standard, so if you're writing your code for an old standard then you will have to use `new` instead, e.g. `genObj.reset(new books)`.)

Also as a side note, make `mode` of an enum type, so that you don't have to handle magic numbers and can replace `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` with some descriptive names such as `mode::phones`, `mode::computers`, `mode::shoes`, and `mode::books` respectively.

Comment: You should add that this will only work in C++14 (because of `make_unique<>`). And since you're at it, he may as well use enum classes instead of just enums.

Comment: @Blito Added a note about that. And aren't scoped enums enums as well? I didn't dismiss the option of scoped enums, in fact I even hinted at it by using the `mode::` prefix.

Comment: Yes, they are. The difference is that by using just enums he could also use plain integers instead of `mode::phones`, etc. The `mode::` prefix can be used in (old) enums too, so it's ambiguous. It's just a detail.

Answer (score 0):

`switch` construction won't handle dynamic allocation of objects for you. It'll be much better to employ a fabric here with common interface or abstract class (depending on your needs), say class `IFace`, and then have a local variable `IFace *genObj` and then make it equal to `new some_derived_from_IFace`.